# Conditionally change strings to factors, based on unique values?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set where many of the character columns should be factors. I can tell which by the number of unique values in them.

To change these columns to factor, I tried:

`mutate_if((is_character(.) & n_distinct(.) <=10), as_factor)`

But got

`Error in tbl_if_vars(.tbl, .p, .env, ..., .include_group_vars = .include_group_vars) : length(.p) == length(tibble_vars) is not TRUE`

I also tried:

`mutate_all(~ if_else((is_character(.) & n_distinct(.) <=10), as.factor), .)`

but got:

`Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "formula"`

I'm guessing it's a simple syntax error, but I'm not familiar with more complex uses of these functions.

How can I efficiently change to `factor` any `character` column that has 10 or fewer unique values?

Answer (score 3):

`help(mutate_if)` says this about the `.predicate` argument

> This argument is passed to rlang::as_function()

`help(as_function)` says x must be

> A function or formula.

So you need to give `mutate_if` either a function or a formula. You can make your input a formula by putting a `~` at the start

```
tibble(a = 'a', b = 3) %>% 
  mutate_if((is_character(.) & n_distinct(.) <=10), as_factor)

# Error in tbl_if_vars(.tbl, .p, .env, ..., .include_group_vars = .include_group_vars) : 
#   length(.p) == length(tibble_vars) is not TRUE

tibble(a = 'a', b = 3) %>% 
  mutate_if(~(is_character(.) & n_distinct(.) <=10), as_factor)

# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#   a         b
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 a         3
```

Note: I don't quote the documentation in order to make a "RTFM" point, just want to show how I got this info

Comment: Amazing—thanks so much. The documentation commentary is SUPER helpful, and greatly appreciated :).

Comment: For accuracy's sake, I noticed I used the wrong condition for the second clause—it should be `n_distinct(.) <= 10`. I fixed it in the question, but can't make the edit in your answer.